# how can i delete one alarm not all alarms?

Tags: android, alarm

i developed an android app to fire notification by alarm manager .
Now I want to cancel one alarm that fire a notification i saw this code but it deletes all alarms 
how can i delete one alarm i want

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
               0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

// this line for cancellation
alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc of [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) says:

> Remove any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)), will be canceled.

So, if you want to be able to delete a specific intent you must be able to differentiate all the intent you are launching.
If your intent is an explicit one, I suggest adding an Action after its creation.

In this way the filterEquals will take that into account and delete only the relevant one.

Something like:

```
Intent intentYouWantToCancel = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
intentYouWantToCancel.setAction("aRelevantString");
```

when you set the alarmmanager as well as when you want to delete it.